# populating a vector list using a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm working through an exercise in which I have to create a Name_pairs class consisting of a vector name and vector age, and populate these based on input from the user.

My main() is as follows:

'''

```
int main() {
    Name_pairs np;
    np.read_names();
    np.read_ages();
    np.print();

        return 0;
}
```

'''

So far my book has taught me to do a use a for-loop for this, and to exit by hitting ctrl+z. This is the code I have so far

'''

```
void Name_pairs::read_names(){
    std::cout <<"Enter a list of names: ";

    for(std::string nl; std::cin>>nl;)
        name.push_back(nl);
}
```

'''

I would then type my names in (ex. Bob, Linda, Gene), enter key, then ctrl+z to escape the loop. What I expected to happen was that I would return to main(), then my next function read_ages() would be called, with similar code

'''

```
void Name_pairs::read_ages(){
    std::cout<<"Enter a list of ages: ";
    for(double uages; std::cin>>uages;)
        age.push_back(uages);
}
```

'''
However, my program seems to terminate upon ctrl+z. My questions really are:
1. Is this type of for-loop good practice? Or is it just being presented to get other points across for a beginner?
2. Why does my program seem to terminate once ctrl+z is entered?

Edit: Apologies, below is the full program I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Name_pairs{
public:
    void read_names();
    void read_ages();
    void print ()const;
    void sort();


private:
    vector <string> name;
    vector <double> age;
};

int main() {
    Name_pairs np;
    np.read_names();
    np.read_ages();
    np.print();

        return 0;
}

void Name_pairs::read_names(){
    cout <<"Enter a list of names: ";

    for(string nl;cin>>nl;)
        name.push_back(nl);
}

void Name_pairs::read_ages(){
    cout<<"Enter a list of ages: ";
    for(double uages; cin>>uages;)
        age.push_back(uages);
}

void Name_pairs::print()const{
    for(size_t i=0;i<name.size();++i)
        cout<<name[i] << "age, "<<age[i]<<'\n';
}
```

Comment: What book are you using so everyone can be advised to avoid it...

Comment: *"Is this type of for-loop good practice?"* Yes. *"Why does my program seem to terminate once ctrl+z is entered?"* Who knows. You didn't put a [mcve].

Comment: ^Z is end-of-file.  You would need t clear that before you can read again.

Comment: Improper condition in `print` if vector sizes differ.